# javax.jms.TextMessage - getStringProperty() returning null value

Tags: java, events, jms, message, tibco

I am listening to a Queue , when a message is posted on to the queue my listener class will listen the message and it has to process it.

Listener configuration is good and i am able to receive the message . But when i try to get the value of one of the property , it is returning null even the property has value for it.

Please see the attached code and my processing logic code.

```
<textMessages>
<textMessage timestamp="1410889863339">
    <property name="evnt_code" value="ID" />
    <property name="prev_cmdy_abrv" value="APOISN" />
    <text><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><ceo_eqmt_msg version="1.1"><eqmt eqmt_nbr="902721" eqmt_init="UTLX" ceo_eqmt_id="56081806"><evnt_dtl><evnt evnt_id="19776586731" evnt_code="ID" stop_code="CU" in_out_stop_ind="O" evnt_dt="20140916124600" le_code="L" wb_nbr="161734" wb_date="20140911" evnt_stn_id="8578" evnt_crc7="B 649" evnt_tz="0" evnt_carr_abrv="CN" yard_bloc_id="CNGI" tcs_csn="1102243807" last_uptd_dt="20140916125101" upd_task_user_id="DAEI999" upd_task_id="=WO" upd_task_dt="20140916125100" match_plnd_ev_id="26624105732" phys_le_code="L" upd_src_sys_tla_code="TCS" upd_src_sys_proc_id="Q133703AEI" evnt_stop_desc_id="2059"/></evnt_dtl></eqmt></ceo_eqmt_msg>]]></text>
</textMessage>
```

Processing as

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    try {       
        TextMessage textMessage         =   (TextMessage) message;
        String stringProperty = textMessage.getStringProperty("evnt_code");
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting property: " + propertyName + " error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting value as a null. even though 'evnt_code' property is existed in  tag and inside the text message.

Help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The message, (payload posted on EMS) as posted is not proper XML.
Could you post the actual message payload as you see it in the EMS Queue or Topic using Gems?

If the message is not proper, a.k.a the payload of the message is not proper xml the parser will never find the children elements, and will return null in the above case the list of properties are children of "textMessage" but it is not clear what is the root of this xml document.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is setting Target Client to JMS in the queue properties on Websphere MQ server